# Entity Framework Core modular approach with multiple contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am looking for the right approach to divide a big application into multiple DB schemas and DB Contexts. The idea is to allow plugins to be installed into the application that manage their own part of the schema.

The application would include a base context that defines things common to all plugins, for the example it's the 'Machines' table:

```
[Table("Machines", Schema = EntitiesConstants.CommonSchema)]
public class Machine 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class CommonContext : DbContext 
{
  public DbSet<Machine> Machines {get;set;}

  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {
      // configure the name and schema for the migrations table
      optionsBuilder
          .UseNpgsql(cs, x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable(EntitiesConstants.MigrationsTable, EntitiesConstants.CommonSchema))
          .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
  }
}
```

There would be another context in the plugin:

```
[Table("Telemetry", Schema = EntitiesConstants.TelemetrySchema)]
public class Telemetry 
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public Machine Machine {get;set;}
  public DateOffset Time {get;set;}
  public string Value {get;set;}
}

public class TelemetryContext : DbContext 
{
  // add the needed entities from the CommonContext to allow EF to query them / build relations with them
  public DbSet<Machine> Machines {get;set;}

  public DbSet<Telemetry> Telemetry {get;set;}

  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
  {
      // configure the name and schema for the migrations table
      optionsBuilder
          .UseNpgsql(cs, x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable(EntitiesConstants.MigrationsTable, EntitiesConstants.TelemetrySchema))
          .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
  }

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
  {
    // ignore the machine table, because it's defined in the CommonContext
    builder.Ignore<Machine>();
  }
}
```

But this does not work. The relation to the machine is ignored, because the machine table is ignored. If I add the relation manually like this:

```
builder.Entity<Telemetry>()
    .HasOne<Machine>(x => x.Machine)
    .WithMany();
```

Then the machine appears also in the migrations for the TelemetryContext.

Is there a solution to this problem? How to have plugins with an application based on EF Core that have foreign key constraints?